# Differentiation between domestication and taming

Tags: discussion, tags

We have some tags that aren't quite being used right and it's bothering me.

The tag [domestication](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domestication) tends to be used where I would use [feral](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feral) or something that doesn't exist (maybe taming?).

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tame_animal#Taming_versus_domestication):

> Domestication should not be confused with taming. Taming is the
>   conditioned behavioral modification of a wild-born animal when its
>   natural avoidance of humans is reduced and it accepts the presence of
>   humans, but domestication is the permanent genetic modification of a
>   bred lineage that leads to an inherited predisposition toward humans.
>   Human selection included tameness, but domestication is not achieved
>   without a suitable evolutionary response. Domestic animals need not be
>   tame in the behavioral sense, such as the Spanish fighting bull. Wild
>   animals can be tame, such as a hand-raised cheetah. A domestic
>   animal's breeding is controlled by humans and its tameness and
>   tolerance of humans is genetically determined.

**Domestication** is a multi-generational process that changes the genetics of a group of animals (with a preference towards traits like tameness and usefulness to humans).

**Taming** is the behavior modification of a single animal.

A good case study of the difference in taming and domestication can be found by reading the large variety of articles and papers written on the [Russian Domestic Fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Domesticated_Red_Fox).

Additionally, a **feral** animal is the opposite of a tame animal. A feral animal is a domesticated animal that is no longer conditioned to accept humans.

### Current Usage

The only question that's currently tagged [domestication](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domestication) that I believe fits that definition is: 
[Where do domesticated cats come from?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7200/where-do-domesticated-cats-come-from) I think it would be fine with the other two tags it has ([cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cats) and [history](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)).

A second question with the tag is a little more arguable: [Are there native web building spiders in North America that can be domesticated?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5919/are-there-native-web-building-spiders-in-north-america-that-can-be-domesticated) The other parts of the question (how do I support a spider) indicate to me that the intent is to tame a single spider, not start a breeding program to genetically modify a line of spiders.

In some places, [domestication](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domestication) is used because [feral](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feral) is not appropriate (the species isn't a domesticated species), such as [How to "re-tame" my captive shingleback](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10830/how-to-re-tame-my-captive-shingleback)

Most of the [feral](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feral) questions are about cats, but I know we've had a large number of questions about feral dogs (mostly from questioners in India, where they're a lot more common). Is there something about the [feral](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feral) tag that people associate with cats?

### Examples of misused [domestication](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domestication)

This is a record of posts I've removed [domestication](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domestication) from to get an idea of how widespread this problem is.

- 9/5/17: [Taming feral cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18234/taming-feral-cats)
- 9/12/17: [Cat in a electronics hobbyist house](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18328/cat-in-a-electronics-hobbyist-house#)

Comment: To add to the confusion, we also have a tag for strays. It may be too much to expect a casual pet owner to understand the nuanced differences between domestication/taming and ferals/strays but I'm not sure the best way to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I propose adding [taming](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taming) and eliminating [domestication](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domestication).

Ideally, typing [domestication] would pop up both [feral](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feral) and [taming](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taming), but I'm not sure if that's possible.